# 'undefined reference to vtable' for abstract class (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, vtable, undefined-reference

I'm writing a library for parsing expressions into a tree structure and I have an abstract type `QCExpressionNode` as my base class. It looks like this:

```
#ifndef QCEXPRESSIONNODE_H
#define QCEXPRESSIONNODE_H

#include <QString>

class QCExpressionNode
{
public:
    virtual ~QCExpressionNode() {}

    virtual float evaluate(float* x) = 0;
    virtual bool containsVariable() = 0;
    virtual QString infixNotation() = 0;
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(QCExpressionNode, "org.nathanmoos.qcalc.libexprtree-qt.QCExpressionNode/0.1")

#endif // QCEXPRESSIONNODE_H
```

When I compile some tests (another project in QtCreator) that work on subclasses (`QCConstantNode`, `QCVariableNode`, `QCBinaryOperatorNode`, and so on), the linker gives me a 'undefined reference to vtable' error for QCExpressionNode. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#include <QtPlugin>`, then the file should compile just fine. 
`Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` is declared in `QtPlugin`.

By the way: it's quite unusual to compile header files by themselves and it's unusual to have include guards outside header files.

Comment: I'm new to C++ and Qt development, so what actually happens to a header file in that situation?

Comment: @Oswald: It's pretty useless *not* to compile header files, and he doesn't have include guards outside of one. Usually you'd compile a header "by proxy", by `#include`ing it in a "source" file, whose preprocessed remains get eaten by the compiler stage. I don't see how that's relevant here, though.

Comment: Aside from the fact that I do not know what `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` expands to, your class is completely defined and compiling it should result in object code just as it would if it were defined in any other C++ file. It's just that header files are not used that way. Header files are included in other files to make their definition known to the other file. This comes in handy if you want to use objects of type `QCExpressionNode` in many other source files.

Comment: @Tomalak When I compile a file `foo.xyz`, I expect a file `foo.o` as a result. Assuming `foo.xyz` includes `bar.xyz`, I will not get a file `bar.o` as a result of compiling `foo.xyz`. So one can argue that `bar.xyz` is indeed not compiled when `foo.xyz` is compiled, but copied into a `foo.i` that is compiled without running the preprocessor. But one can also see it from your point of view.

Comment: @Oswald: I see yours too. I guess it's semantics as to whether you consider an individual file to be "compiled" if its contents were compiled as part of some other file. Personally I try not to dwell on the concept of a "file". (I don't get the bit about "without running the preprocessor", though.)

Comment: @Oswald: My question is inaccurate, and I will be rephrasing it now.